# fread skip argument not consistent

Tags: r, data.table

Ok, I know this is not a reproducible example, because I only managed to get this error with this specific data.table, that has almost 1gb, so I don't know how to send it to you. Anyway, I am completely lost... If someone knows what is happening here, please tell me.

I have the original data.table and some other ones obtained by just changing the skip argument.

```
> original <- fread('json.csv')
> skip100 <- fread('json.csv', skip = 100, sep = ',')
> skip1000 <- fread('json.csv', skip = 1000, sep = ',')
> skip10000 <- fread('json.csv', skip = 10000, sep = ',')

> str(original)
    Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  29315 obs. of  7 variables:
     $ id         : chr  "0015023cc06b5362d332b3baf348d11567ca2fbb" "004f0f8bb66cf446678dc13cf2701feec4f36d76" "00d16927588fb04d4be0e6b269fc02f0d3c2aa7b" "0139ea4ca580af99b602c6435368e7fdbefacb03" ...
     $ title      : chr  "The RNA pseudoknots in foot-and-mouth disease virus are dispensable for genome replication but essential for th"| __truncated__ "Healthcare-resource-adjusted vulnerabilities towards the 2019-nCoV epidemic across China" "Real-time, MinION-based, amplicon sequencing for lineage typing of infectious bronchitis virus from upper respiratory samples" "A Combined Evidence Approach to Prioritize Nipah Virus Inhibitors" ...
     $ authors    : chr  "Joseph C Ward,Lidia  Lasecka-Dykes,Chris  Neil,Oluwapelumi  Adeyemi,Sarah  ,  Gold,Niall  Mclean,Caroline  Wrig"| __truncated__ "Hanchu  Zhou,Jiannan  Yang,Kaicheng  Tang,â\200   ,Qingpeng  Zhang,Zhidong  Cao,Dirk  Pfeiffer,Daniel Dajun Zeng" "Salman L Butt,Eric C Erwood,Jian  Zhang,Holly S Sellers,Kelsey  Young,Kevin K Lahmers,James B Stanton" "Nishi  Kumari,Ayush  Upadhyay,Kishan  Kalia,Rakesh  Kumar,Kanika  Tuteja,Rani  Paul,Eugenia  Covernton,Tina  Sh"| __truncated__ ...
     $ institution: chr  "" "City University of Hong Kong,City University of Hong Kong,City University of Hong Kong,NA,City University of Ho"| __truncated__ "University of Georgia,University of Georgia,University of Georgia,University of Georgia,University of Georgia,V"| __truncated__ "Panjab University,Delhi University,D.A.V. College,CSIR-Institute of Microbial Technology,Panjab University,Univ"| __truncated__ ...
     $ country    : chr  "" "China,China,China,NA,China,China,China,China" "USA,USA,USA,USA,USA,USA,USA" "India,India,India,India,India,India,France,India,NA,India" ...
     $ abstract   : chr  "word count: 194 22 Text word count: 5168 23 24 25 author/funder. All rights reserved. No reuse allowed without "| __truncated__ "" "Infectious bronchitis (IB) causes significant economic losses in the global poultry industry. Control of infect"| __truncated__ "Nipah Virus (NiV) came into limelight recently due to an outbreak in Kerala, India. NiV causes severe disease a"| __truncated__ ...
     $ body_text  : chr  "VP3, and VP0 (which is further processed to VP2 and VP4 during virus assembly) (6). The P2 64 and P3 regions en"| __truncated__ "The 2019-nCoV epidemic has spread across China and 24 other countries 1-3 as of February 8, 2020 . The mass qua"| __truncated__ "Infectious bronchitis (IB), which is caused by infectious bronchitis virus (IBV), is one of the most important "| __truncated__ "Nipah is an infectious negative-sense single-stranded RNA virus which belongs to the genus henipavirus and fami"| __truncated__ ...
     - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

The number of observations is consistent for skip = 100 and 10000, but not for skip = 1000, as shown below.

```
> nrow(original)
[1] 29315
> nrow(skip100)
[1] 29215
> nrow(skip1000)
[1] 28316
> nrow(skip10000)
[1] 19315
```

[image]

What is happening?

Comment: Hi result looks okay.code is doing work i thing.what is the error you facing?

Comment: Hi. The number of observations in skip1000 should be 28315...

Comment: Yes.. understood.try with ```header="auto" ,na.strings="NA", stringsAsFactors=FALSE ``` this might help.

Comment: Just tried... same thing

Comment: Just tried with read_csv from readr... Apparently it works fine, at least for the number of rows.

Comment: Great. But we should keep this is in observation until the issue gets resolve or why function is giving such results.